# how to display 15 product from category having multiple subcategories in random order in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

I have 3 tables:

```
homepage
    order- integer
    status - boolean
    product_category_id - integer

category
    name- string
    slug- slug
    parent_id- integer

product
    name- string
    category_id- integer
```

When user wish to have categories in homepage like this
[image]

I want to have 15 products from categories in homepage including products from subcategories in random order. So far what i have done is

```
 //  all categories to be posted in homepage.
        $hp_categories = HomepageCategory::asc()->active()->get();

        foreach ($hp_categories as $hp_cat) {
            // array declaration
            $cat_with_subcat_arr = [];
            // category
            $product_category = ProductCategory::where('id', $hp_cat->product_category_id)->first();            
            // push category's id to array
            array_push($cat_with_subcat_arr, $product_category->id);
            // subcategories if any.
            $product_category->childrenCategoriesIds($cat_with_subcat_arr);
            
            // product from categories and subcategories via whereIn.
            $products = Product::whereIN('product_category_id', $cat_with_subcat_arr)->inRandomOrder()->limit(15)->get();
                    
            dd($products);
        }
        return $hp_categories;
```

my output is like this
[image]

Note: I could not do it by eager loading. So, I did by simple logic but cannot pass data to view.

Comment: `Product::all()->unique('category_id')->slice(0, 15);` Try that

Comment: Thank you! I got 15 unique product without repetition from any category. But the real question is how to send 15 product of each  category that user wish to send to homepage like i mentioned in image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller i did

```
//define a collection;
$hp_cats = collect();

foreach ($hp_categories as $key=>$hp_cat) {

    // array declaration
    $cat_with_subcat_arr = [];

    // category
    $product_category = ProductCategory::where('id', $hp_cat->product_category_id)->first();            
 
    // push category's id to array
            
    array_push($cat_with_subcat_arr, $product_category->id);
            
    // subcategories if any.
            
    $product_category->childrenCategoriesIds($cat_with_subcat_arr);
            
            
    // product from categories and subcategories via whereIn.
            
    $products = Product::whereIN('product_category_id', $cat_with_subcat_arr)
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->limit(15)
            ->get();
            
            
    $hp_cats[$key] = $products;
        
}
```

the result
[image]

Note: I could not found answer so it may not be the best solution. any help is appriciated.